# How to detect whether the browser window has opened from another browser window?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, web-applications, browser

We are developing Java-Gwt web application and we have a login page to access the application. Recently we had facing 
one scenario which is described below.

1) The user opens the application in one browser window (say Chrome) and login page will show to the user.
2) The user again opens the same application in another browser window (say Chrome) and there also login page will show to the user.

here, the user enters the login credentials and access the application from the first browser window, then again user enters the 
different login credentials in the second browser window and access the application. Here We have opened application with two different
credentials in 2 browser windows even though the browser instance is same.

If we do like above we are going into inconsistency state as per our implementation.

What is the best way of doing in the above case?

I have observed in 'Gmail' application with the above explained case, It is reloading the second window if the user logs in first window.

If We consider 'Gmail' is good example how to detect second browser window from first window in GWT or JavaScript?

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Are you trying to support simultaneous multiple accounts just like Gmail. For detecting log in another window, I think it should be based on session. If second window can detect asynchronously that a session has been created, the page can be reloaded in the logged in state

Comment: right the user is able to login with multiple accounts in the same browser but different windows, now we wanted to make it like gmail app. We are creating session before displaying login page.

Comment: Are you not able to detect session across windows

Comment: @nitigyan,  we are generating 2 different session ids for 2 windows for our implementation.

Comment: If your sessions are stored in cookies, you shouldn't get two session ids for two windows of the same browser, unless one of those windows is in "Incognito mode" (or similar).  If you are getting that behavior, your server-side session persistence is broken.

Comment: okay @tangent, as you said our cookie is one cookie that will be updated when we try to access the 2nd time login message, then how we can detect 2nd window opened in gwt

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I misunderstood your question.  So you have cookie/HTTP sessions implemented properly, and the following occurs:

1. A user loads the login page in two browser windows (or tabs) of the same browser application.  A single HTTP session (unauthenticated) and corresponding browser cookie are created (on the first load).
2. User logs in as user A in the first window, which updates the session and cookie to reflect that user A is logged in.
3. User then logs in as user B in the second window, which updates the session and cookie to reflect that user A is logged in.
4. If your app has user-specific content, user A's data will still be displayed in the first browser window, but refreshing the page or browsing around will show that it's really user B logged in.

None of this behavior is indicative of a problem, but you'd like to be able to detect when this has happened (or at least steps 1-3).  To do this, I would recommend storing something about the user in the session/cookie after authentication, such as an ID (you may already be doing this).  When setting this value in the HTTP session/cookie, first check to see if there's already a non-null value in it.  If so, then you have successfully detected the scenario above.

So after authentication, something like this, where request is the HttpServletRequest:

```
    Integer userId = (Integer) request.getSession().getAttribute("userId");
    if (userId != null && userId != newlyAuthenticatedUserId) {
        System.out.println("Second login from same browser!");
    }
    request.getSession().setAttribute("userId", userId);
```